# шаблонный обьект и Variadic templates

Tags: c++

Создаю по шаблону разные обьекты:

```
template<typename T>
 T obj = T(5);
using std::cout;
int main()
{
    using V = std::vector<int>;
    cout << obj<int> << std::endl;
    obj<V> = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for (int i : obj<V>)
    cout << i << ' ';
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Но еще не пробовал создавать обьекты с разным количеством аргументов в конструкторе. Как переписать шаблон и как создавать обьект вышеуказанным способом, чтобы указать 2 и более аргумента конструктора? (Например, мой шаблон не позволит создать специализацию для `std::vector<int>(10, 15)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю, правильно ли понял, что нужно, но вот как можно

```
template <class T, auto k = 5, auto... args>
T obj = T(k, args...);

int main() {

    using V = std::vector<int>;
    using M = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

    cout << obj<int> << std::endl;

    for (auto i : obj<V, 10, 15>)
        cout << i << ' ';

    cout << endl;

    obj<M> = { {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} };
    for (auto i : obj<M>) {
        for (auto x : i) {
            cout << x << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вы все верно понели и написали то, что нужно